# vecp vs vech operator on symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, vectorization

Let $\mathbf{X}$ $(p \times p)$ be a symmetric matrix.
The vecp operator stacks the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ **above** and including the diagonal columnwise.
The vech operator stacks the elements of $\mathbf{X}$ **below** and including the diagonal columnwise.

$$
\text{vecp}(\mathbf{X}) = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} \\ x_{12} \\ x_{22} \\ \vdots \\ x_{1p} \\ \vdots \\x_{pp} \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad
\text{vech}(\mathbf{X}) = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} \\ x_{21} \\ \vdots \\ x_{p1} \\ x_{22} \\ \vdots \\ x_{p2} \\ \vdots \\x_{pp} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be the unique matrices defined by $\text{vec}(\mathbf{X})= \mathbf{A} \text{vecp}(\mathbf{X})$ and $\text{vec}(\mathbf{X})= \mathbf{B} \text{vech}(\mathbf{X})$, respectively.

How are the matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ related?

Comment: There exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $AP = B$. In other words, the matrices have the same columns but in different orders.

Comment: Thisis the text of your homework. What have you tried ? Have you attempted for example to understand the case $n=3$? Do you have an idea of the sizes of matrices $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, no this is not a homework question.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, I got it.

Comment: You have a detailed answer in this [article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2929422)

Comment: @JeanMarie I found that article, too. There the vecp operator stacks the elements in yet another way, not equal to the vecp operator here (which I found in Gupta & Nagar's book "Matrix variate distributions".).

Comment: And I must admit that I only got so far as to define $P=A^*B$, using the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$. But like this I can never transform $B$ to $A$ without knowing both matrices already.